# Resize Error with Virtual Box and Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualbox-guest-additions

I'm using vagrant to create a Debian/contrib-stretch64. My main problem is that when i try to resize this VM, i got this error:

> Vboxclient: Failed to get display change request,
> rc=VERR_IO_BAD_LENGTH

I tried many things, i switch VBOXVGA to VMSVGA or VBoxSVGA but no result.
I've seen it could be a bad installation of VBox guest additions.
In my vagrant file, i install them this way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
mount /media/cdrom
sudo sh /media/cdroom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run --force
```

With this code, Vagrant try to find linux-headers-4.9.0-12-amd 64 but is unable to find it. (Maybe the mirror are dead)
I also tried to download directly linux-headers-4.9.014-amd64 on the VM and install it directly but there is no change. I also tried to download it on Vagrant:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-4.9.0-14-amd64 build-essential dkms
```

I've change Virtual box 6.1 to 6.0.
And last things, i've seen that my previous build (working) have the same error when i try to rebuild them.